# How to add screenshot using selenum in docker or linux env

Tags: selenium, docker, cucumber, selenium-extent-report

I am tring to add screenshot, whenever my testcases are getting failed. However i have succeeded doing this in Windows env, but i am unable to achieve it in docker/linux env.

code for screenshot:

```
public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws java.lang.Exception 
 {
    Random rand = new Random();
    //Scenario scenario;
     System.out.println("Execution Failure : ");

      try {
            //String screenshotName = failure.getTestHeader().toString();
            int num = rand.nextInt(10000000);
            String screenshotName = "Screenshot"+num;

            /*File sourcePath = ((TakesScreenshot)Homepage.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File destinationPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/CucumberExtentReport/Screenshots/" + screenshotName +".jpeg");
            Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
            Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(destinationPath.toString());
            */
            final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)Homepage.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES); 
            File destinationPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/CucumberExtentReport/Screenshots/" + screenshotName +".jpeg");
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(destinationPath, screenshot);
            //Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
            Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(destinationPath.toString());

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
 }
```

Note: I have used extent reports for adding screenshot on failed testcases...

Comment: What's the value of `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")`? Why are parts of the code commented out?

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir") = D:\p10 next\p10\packages\p10-designer-automation.
Thats the value.

Comment: Ok, so the property user.dir points to `D:\p10 next\p10\packages\p10-designer-automation`? I don't think that will exist on Linux...